# OneHotEncoder removes columns when in pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

This is my `X_train`:

```
> print(type(X_train))
> print(X_train)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
      0  1  2  3  4  5         keyword
1386  2  1  1  0  1  1    bush%20fires
4048  0  1  1  0  1  0  forest%20fires
3086  0  0  0  0  0  0     electrocute
272   0  0  0  1  0  0      apocalypse
7462  0  0  0  0  0  0          wounds
...  .. .. .. .. .. ..             ...
4931  0  1  0  0  1  0          mayhem
3264  0  1  0  0  1  0        engulfed
1653  0  2  0  0  2  0       collapsed
2607  0  0  0  0  0  0       destroyed
2732  0  0  0  0  0  0      devastated

[6090 rows x 7 columns]
```

And this is the preprocessing code I run on `X_train`:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

numeric_features = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median"))]
)

categorical_features = ["keyword"]

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
            ("transformer", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num", numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ]
)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor)]
)

X_train = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = pipeline.transform(X_test)
```

Because I'm using `OneHotEncoder` on the "keyword" column, I expect there to be a bunch of new columns added for each of the possible values of "keyword". I also expect my numeric columns to be preserved the way they were before.

But... this is what `X_train` becomes after preprocessing:

```
> print(type(X_train))
> print(pd.DataFrame(X_train))

<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
                                                  0
0       (0, 0)\t2.0\n  (0, 1)\t1.0\n  (0, 2)\t1.0\n ...
1       (0, 1)\t1.0\n  (0, 2)\t1.0\n  (0, 4)\t1.0\n ...
2                                          (0, 94)\t1.0
3                           (0, 3)\t1.0\n  (0, 13)\t1.0
4                                         (0, 223)\t1.0
...                                                 ...
6085        (0, 1)\t1.0\n  (0, 4)\t1.0\n  (0, 148)\t1.0
6086         (0, 1)\t1.0\n  (0, 4)\t1.0\n  (0, 99)\t1.0
6087         (0, 1)\t2.0\n  (0, 4)\t2.0\n  (0, 53)\t1.0
6088                                       (0, 80)\t1.0
6089                                       (0, 84)\t1.0

[6090 rows x 1 columns]
```

As you can see, the `OneHotEncoder` hasn't worked, and somehow the numeric columns are also gone.

Why this is the case and how to fix it?

Comment: The `OneHotEncoder ` is not being used because the `categorical_transformer ` is not included in the list of transformers in the `preprocessor ` , only the `numeric_transformer ` is included. What do you mean when you say that the numeric columns are gone?

Comment: Whoops, I should've included it. Just updated it.

Comment: Still the numeric columns are present in your presented post-transform data.  Did you copy the wrong thing?  Can you provide a smaller version of your dataset that we can copy and run to reproduce this?

Comment: Whoops again, just put the correct output.

Comment: for a cleaner representation, you might think of transforming `X_train` to array (`X_train.toarray()`) before passing it to `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

`OneHotEncoder` transforms into sparse array format, and `ColumnTransformer` does so if enough of its component outputs do so. In your case, that appears to be the case, and trying to cast directly to dataframe breaks.

However, you can see in the output that things have happened correctly: e.g.,
`1653  0  2  0  0  2  0       collapsed`
in the input becomes
`6087 (0, 1)\t2.0\n (0, 4)\t2.0\n (0, 53)\t1.0`
The `6087` is just a reset index. The `(0, 1)\t2.0\n` says there's a 2.0 in the column indexed 1 (second column), similarly a 2.0 in column 4, the two nonzero numeric values.  And finally in column 53 there is a 1.0, the result of the encoding of "collapsed".  All others are 0, which aren't saved in memory for the sparse format.

I think the best solution is to convert the sparse output into a sparse pandas structure:

```py
out = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)
out_df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(out, columns=pipeline.get_feature_names_out())
```

But you could also force a dense representation, either manually with `out.toarray()`, or by setting the encoder's setting `sparse=False` or the column transformer's `sparse_threshold=0`.

Comment: I get an error when I do `columns=pipeline.get_feature_names_out()`: 
AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out'

Comment: @AA1227 what version of sklearn are you running?  The newest versions should work.  Otherwise, you can reconstruct the feature names a bit manually, and using the old `OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names`.